# HandleUnauthorizedRequest goes in InfiniteLoop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have following two actions that keeps calling each other and goes in infinite loop. what am i doing wrong?

```
Public Overrides Sub OnAuthorization(filterContext As System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext)
        'This calls the AuthorzeCore function and also makes sure that the browser does not cache this function
        MyBase.OnAuthorization(filterContext)
        If Not IsNothing(filterContext.Result) Then
            Return
        End If
        'Gets the calling Controller
        Dim controllerName As String = filterContext.Controller.GetType().Name
        'Gets the calling action
        Dim actionName As String = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName

        'Checks whether the logged in user has access to the action of the controller
        Dim canAccess As test.Security.Permissions.PermissionTypes
        canAccess = test.ApplicationSecurity.GetSecurityObject().GetAccess(controllerName & "." & actionName)
        If canAccess = Security.Permissions.PermissionTypes.DISABLE Then
            'User has access to the application but not to the action they are trying to access, so throw a Unauthorised exception
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403
            HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext)
        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext As System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext)
        ''To make sure that we throw a not authorised error rather not authenticated message
        'If filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated Then
        '    'filterContext.Result = New HttpStatusCodeResult(CType(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, Int32))
        '    filterContext.Result = New RedirectToRouteResult(
        'Else
        '    MyBase.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext)
        'End If
        If (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) Then
            Dim urlHelper As UrlHelper = New UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext)
            filterContext.Result = New JsonResult With {.Data = New With {.Error = "NotAuthorized", .URL = urlHelper.Action("UnAuthorized", "Error")}, _
                                                        .JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet}
        ElseIf filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403 Then
            filterContext.Result = New ViewResult With {.ViewName = "UnAuthorized"}
        Else
            filterContext.Result = New ViewResult With {.ViewName = "UnAuthenticated"}

        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` from inside `OnAuthorization`, this method is called automatically when the request can't be authorized.

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.authorizeattribute.onauthorization%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

> Authorization is denied in the following cases:
>
> • The request is not associated with any user.
>
> • The user is not authenticated.
>
> • The user is authenticated but is not in the authorized group of Userss (if defined), or if the user is not in any
>   of the authorized Roles (if defined).
>
> If authorization is denied then this method will invoke
>   HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext) to process the
>   unauthorized request.

Comment: if i remove the handleunauthorizedrequest call from the onauthorisation function, then it just ignores that i have set the statuscode to 403 and display the page.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a good practise but it works, if i add this line instead of setting the status code to 403 in the authorisation function                                                     filterContext.Result = New ViewResult With {.ViewName = "UnAuthorized"}

Comment: That isn't really the recommended way of doing it, use [HttpUnauthorizedResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpunauthorizedresult(v=vs.108).aspx) e.g. `filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult()`.

Comment: if i do that, then it just basically displays a username and password pop up box to the user, rather than displaying a specific view with the error message i want. any other way i can do that?

Comment: Actually thinking more about this, the `OnAuthorization` isn't really the best place to be doing custom authorization, you should override [AuthorizeCore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.authorizecore(v=vs.98).aspx) instead and do it in there. That way you simply return a boolean to indicate whether or not the request has been authorized.

Comment: i can't do that because to do custom authorisation i need access to Controller and action that is calling for authorisation purposes.

Comment: You can get access to the controller via the `httpContext` see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302444/can-i-get-the-controller-from-the-httpcontext)