# Get Controller/Action context from a given URI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a .NET Core 3.1 MVC application that uses

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
```

to map all my controllers, which are using attributes to determine routes.  There is nothing else fancy going on.

What I want is to create a method that takes a `string url` parameter, that returns me information about what controller and action that url would hit.  I want to use this to build up breadcrumbs based on the current url.

My thought is to hack the current request url apart backwards by `/`, and derive the controller and action for each url sub part.  I want to use this along with a custom attribute to derive the breadcrumb names and descriptions.

I had thought this would be something that was commonly asked for, but I am having an incredibly hard time finding any helpful answers.  I fully expected that I could inject some sort of `IMyRoutingConfiguration` type object that had a method like `GetRouteContextForUri`.  But I am having zero luck.

Is there a way to access the internal router, so that I can supply it a relative or absolute url, and get back context about which controller/action it would choose based on the setup of the site?

Comment: You can use HttpContext in custom attribute to get the route data. and access ["controller"] from route data to get the controller name. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302444/can-i-get-the-controller-from-the-httpcontext

Comment: If you are creating attribute by inheriting FilterAttribute, you can use filterContext too. https://forums.asp.net/t/1533590.aspx?Getting+Controller+and+Action+from+HttpContext

Comment: Have you looked at `HttpContext.GetRouteData()` or `HttpContext.GetRouteValue()` extension: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.routinghttpcontextextensions?view=aspnetcore-3.1? Also in order to get the `HttpContext`, you can inject `IHttpContextAccesor` in your controllers.

Comment: Right, I can use the HttpContext to get the current requests’ route info, but I want to supply a url and get the route info for any endpoint unrelated to the current request