# How to find controller name in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

How to find the controller name in ASP.NET Core?

I googled it, very first I got the solution `ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerName`.

But in my ASP.NET Core application, `ControllerContext` is not showing any properties.

Please help me.

Comment: I tested this inside a controller method in a Core 5 MVC app, and it worked: `var controllerName = ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerName;`

Comment: In controller I'm also able to find it but class it's not working.

Comment: Well, that is something you should mention in your question. Some reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302444/can-i-get-the-controller-from-the-httpcontext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using ASP.NET Core 3+, you can utilize endpoint routing and get the current endpoint inside a controller action.

Controller actions have a `ControllerActionDescriptor` metadata, which provides you info about the action.

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("")]
public class HelloController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var endpoint = HttpContext.GetEndpoint();
        var actionDescriptor = endpoint!.Metadata.OfType<ControllerActionDescriptor>().First()!;
        var controllerName = actionDescriptor.ControllerName;  
        // -> gives you "Hello"
        
        return Ok(controllerName);
    }
}
```

If you're looking for the fully-qualified name, you can use the controller type info

```cs
var controllerFullName = actionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.FullName; 
// -> gives you "ApiPlayground.HelloController"
```