# Having an HttpContext how can I get the "MethodInfo" of the action that is going to be executed?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, nlog, .net-4.8

I have the following code:

```
    [LayoutRenderer("http-request")]
    public class NLogHttpRequestLayoutRenderer : AspNetRequestPostedBody
    {     
        protected override void DoAppend(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
        {
            base.DoAppend(builder, logEvent);
            var body = builder.ToString();
            
           // after getting the type of the action's request model do serialization deserialization things ...
          
        }
```

This is my `nLog` renderer. It will render every request body into the log system. But some bodies contain sensitive data like emails or bank cards. I want to mask the data. To do that, I need to understand what is the type of the action request.
Considering, I have the following action:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/v1/payment/pay")]
        [MaskRequestMethod(typeof(PaymentRequest))]
        public Task<BankCardActionResponse> Pay([FromBody] PaymentRequest request)
        {
            if (request == null)
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

            return _paymentService.PayAsync(SsoHelper.Ctn, request);
        }
```

The question is, how can I get into the renderer the `MethodInfo` of the action if I have the `HttpContext`. Because if I get the `MethodInfo` I can retrieve the attribute `[MaskRequestMethod(typeof(PaymentRequest))]` and get the `Type` from the attribute. Having that `Type`, I can deserialize JSON body, mask it according to programmed in advance rules and serialize it again. That was the short explanation why do I need it at all.

So, the question: if I have the `HttpContext` can I get the `MethodInfo` of the action that is going to be executed?

Comment: Maybe try `HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.GetRouteData()?.Values?["action"]?.ToString()`. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-MVC-Action-Layout-Renderer

Answer (score 1):

You can use ActionFilter

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class CustomFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
     {

        var controllerType = context.Controller.GetType();      
        var actionName = ((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionDescriptor)context.ActionDescriptor).ActionName;

        MethodInfo method = controllerType.GetMethod(actionName);

        Type attType = typeof(AsyncStateMachineAttribute);

        // Obtain the custom attribute for the method.
        // The value returned contains the StateMachineType property.
        // Null is returned if the attribute isn't present for the method.
        var attrib = (AsyncStateMachineAttribute)method.GetCustomAttribute(attType);

        //do your stuff....
    }
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // Do something after the action executes.
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's not gonna help me. I need to know the `MethodInfo` not here, but into the renderer in the moment of `DoAppend` method execution.

Comment: You can access HttpContext from `DoAppend` through `HttpContextAccessor`
And use same code I provided above, but extracting actionName through contextAccessor

Comment: There is no the "Controller" property into the `HttpContext`. So, `ActionExecutingContext` is a bit different thing.

Comment: Try this answer instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/9022179/14202100

Comment: There is no guarantee that the controller will only have one method with any given name. `ControllerActionDescriptor` has a `MethodInfo` property. Why not just use that instead of trying to find it based on the name?